# Model construct

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have many reports in web app where there is same UI design: Filter data in the top of page and data table in below.
Filter data can be 10 different kind of `dropdownlist` like: Country, City, StartMonth of smth, EndMonth of smth etc. And there is button Search after pressing it I make request to db and show data in table below filter.

I wondering how you create Model class in such cases? 
Create one Model class for Filter fields and DataTable or something else? 
Now Fitler contain 2 properties for each DropDownList: data source `(Ienumerable<Country>) + selectedCountry`. I know about `FormCollection`, but maybe you can suggest better way

Thank you!

Comment: I Cannot able to understand your question

Comment: Dinesh, common web page, e.g. SalesReport. So, at the top of web page there is a Filter with different select condtions and in the below of Filter there is a data table by that Filter.